# I believe I have committed Zina

Tags: zina

Assalam Walaikum Everyone, hope everyone is doing well Alhamdulilah.

I guess let me start from the beginning. Ever since I was in middle school pornography has affected my life negatively and especially my Iman. These past few months my Iman is completely gone to the point that I don't read Quran or pray Salah and my addiction has been sky-high.

Earlier today, my urges came over me and I participated in giving and receiving oral sex to another woman (a prostitute), not vaginal (I'm a male). Afterwards, I feel disgusted and ashamed of what I have done, and I'm scared that I have committed a major sin. I now plan on praying salah and reading Quran, but most of all cutting pornography out of my life (it will be difficult, wish me luck).

Please let me know if what I have done is major Zina or Makrooh!

Comment: Please avoid sharing (at least in a direct tone) your sins to strangers on internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to know that you are so concerned about terminologies like *Zina* or *Makruh*, but you had oral sex with a prostitute! How does that happen?

For instance, I don't even pray five times a day and I don't think about the nitty-gritty details about Islam. However, I can never think of having oral sex with someone let alone a prostitute.

What I suspect is, you are either in a bad company or you are living in a country where sex is as accessible as the groceries in a supermarket.

Therefore, my suggestion would be either to change your lifestyle by getting rid of bad company or move to a place where casual sex is very restricted or extremely frowned upon or a punishable offense.